# Error installing cvxopt using Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cvxopt

I'm attempting to install cvxopt using Conda (which comes with the Anaconda python distribution), and I received the error message below.  Apparently my Anaconda installation is using python 3.6, whereas cvxopt wants python 3.5*. How can I fix this and install cvxopt using Conda?

After typing conda install cvxopt at the Anaconda prompt, the message I received was:

> Fetching package metadata ...........
>
> Solving package specifications: .
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
> conflict:
>
> ```
> - cvxopt -> python 3.5*
> - python 3.6*
> ```
>
> Use "conda info < package >" to see the dependencies for each package.

Here's a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll delete my comment and this one after a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `cvxopt` requires Python 3.5. Easiest solution would be to use `conda` to create a separate environment for python 3.5 and then install cvxopt (and any other desired python packages). For example...

```
conda create -n cvxopt-env python=3.5 cvxopt numpy scipy matplotlib jupyter
```

...depending on your operating system you can then activate this environment using either...

```
source activate cvxopt-env
```

...or...

```
activate cvxopt-env
```

...you can then switch back to your default python install using...

```
deactivate
```

...check out the [`conda`](https://conda.io/docs/) docs for more details. In particular the docs for the [`conda create`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html) command.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a new Anaconda environment that uses Python 3.5 and has all the standard Anaconda packages by typing `conda create -n python35 python=3.5 anaconda` into the Anaconda prompt.  I activated the new environment with the command `activate python35` (since I'm using Windows) and then I was able to install cvxopt.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
conda install cvxopt=1.1.8
```

its the new version and only version having support for python3.6

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried this I got a PackageNotFoundError.

Comment: Weird, it worked for me. do conda search cvxopt. then select the version which supports python 3.6, by doing conda install cvxopt=version

Comment: Just tried that, the search yielded one result, which was cvxopt version 1.1.9.  So I tried doing conda install cvxopt=1.1.9 and received the same UnsatisfiableError as in my screenshot posted above.

Comment: Might be a Windows issue? It appeared that cvxopt only supported Python 3.6 on OSX and Linux.